# Selenium java test failing with azure pipeline and pass locally

Tags: java, azure, selenium-webdriver

**The below is my code**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(60));
WebElement EnterSearch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.search-input.search1")));
                
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              
Actions a10=new Actions(driver);

a10.moveToElement(EnterSearch) ;

a10.click().build().perform();
```

**below is my div and input element**

```
<input _ngcontent-ynd-c699="" class="search-input search1 d-none d-xl-block ng-tns-c699-7 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" placeholder="Type here to search...">
```

**below is the error**

```
2023-07-20T10:12:43.7055102Z org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.cssSelector: input.search-input.search1 (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
2023-07-20T10:12:43.7056907Z Build info: version: '4.9.0', revision: 'd7057100a6'
2023-07-20T10:12:43.7057705Z System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.19'
2023-07-20T10:12:43.7057975Z Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
2023-07-20T10:12:43.7058908Z Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 115.0.5790.98, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f..., userDataDir: C:\Windows\SystemTemp\scope...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61697}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:61697/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 115.0.5790.98, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
2023-07-20T10:12:43.7059858Z Session ID: 7abe6dbb89cf93e6c1921e65616f0f71
```

I have tried `JavaScriptExecutor` as well if I use that it is giving me `element interactable error`

Comment: Waiting for element to be clickable will fail if the element is already clickable. In case of implicit wait usually no explicite waits are needed.